# Please fix the user card colors in dark mode; they fail contrast tests

Tags: bug, design, accessibility, user-card

A short while ago the dark mode styles updated (or perhaps my cache just refreshed), and the user card background changed from a nice neutral grey (Something like `#3d4951` or very close to it, as I recall) to the same or similar bright blue that the light mode uses:

Before (ish): 
[image: dark grey user card shown]

After: 
[image: bright blue user card shown]

In dark mode, this blue is quite garish (especially considering it's colored while nothing else on the page is), but more importantly, it currently fails [accessibility contrast requirements](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=33A7FF&bcolor=1B4A71):

[image: Contrast Checker results]

I don't know if this change was intentional or not, but, at the very least, the current contrast issue warrants a bug. Personally I would prefer the grey be restored.

Comment: Same report on MSE: [Blue text on blue background for usercard has insufficient contrast](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/369227/289905).

Comment: I legitimately struggle to read the username on the new user card now. That's how I noticed the change.

Comment: My current workaround to this is to use the [High contrast mode beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411820). I was straining to read the text otherwise and for a bit had a custom style set but the high contrast mode works better for more things. That doesn't mean that it shouldn't be fixed in regular dark mode, though.